# Switching columns within a geom_bar() plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have a data set with three different columns. Column one is a "condition" (i.e. vision problems, joint pain, back pain). Column two is a certain time (i.e. "Pre" or "Post"). Column three are the sum of individuals who complain of the condition in the pre and the post time.

```
prepost <- prepost %>% 
   select(pre_vision, post_vision, pre_joint, post_joint, pre_back, post_back)

prevspost <- data.frame(condition = factor(c("Vision","Vision","Joint","Joint", "Back", "Back"),
    time = factor(c("Pre","Post","Pre","Post","Pre","Post")),
    n = colSums(prepost)
)

ggplot(data = prevspost, aes(x=condition, y=n, fill=time)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position=position_dodge()) +
  labs(title = "Health Problems Pre vs. Post Event", x = "Health Ailment", y = "N")
```

This works very well for me except that post appears before pre for each of the conditions. See image belong. I wish to have "Pre" data appear before "Post" data

Plot generated from the above code. I wish to switch the "Pre" and "Post" columns. Insteaf of "post" then "pre", I want to have "pre" then "post". Seems logical right?

[image]

Comment: try adding this `scale_fill_discrete(breaks = c("Pre", "Post"))`

Comment: Factors are ordered alphabetically unless you specify otherwise.  Try `time = factor(c("Pre","Post","Pre","Post","Pre","Post"),levels=c("Pre","Post"))`

Comment: Thanks! Adding levels = c("Pre", "Post")) worked well!